# Google Apps Script: YouTube search is not working with location parameter

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to pull some data using the YouTube Data API via Google Apps Script.

This is what I have done so far and it's working without any issue.

```
   var searchParameter = {
    q: 'javascript',
    maxResults: 50,
    type:'videos'
   }

   var results = YouTube.Search.list('id,snippet', searchParameter);
```

Now I want add location filter to this query.
According to docs I added `location` and `locationRadius` parameters:

```
   var searchParameter = {
    q: 'javascript',
    maxResults: 50,
    type:'videos',
    location: "37.42307,-122.08427",
    locationRadius: "999km",
   }

   var results = YouTube.Search.list('id,snippet', searchParameter);
```

But after adding these 2 parameters, it's not working anymore and I'm getting following error:

`{ [GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to youtube.search.list failed with error: Request contains an invalid argument.] details:  { errors: [ [Object] ], message: 'Request contains an invalid argument.', code: 400 }, name: 'GoogleJsonResponseException' }`.

I'm following this guide:

`https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#location`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You have a typo: replace `type:'videos'` with `type:'video'`. Do notice that `type` is not `videos` but `video`.

Comment: oh man, thanks a lot. you can add it as the answer. thanks a lot

Comment: anyway the summary is type:'videos' is wokring when there is no location paramter, but the correct way is use type:'video' for all scenarios

Comment: According to the accustomed rules of SO, issues caused by typos should be resolved by comments only (not answers).

Comment: ok. anyway thanks for the help again